# Kivy MDLabel просит иницилизировать до подключения

Tags: python, kivy

Запускаю вот этот код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel




class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass
        
class LevelScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingScreen(Screen):
    pass




Builder.load_file("cubes.kv")



sm = ScreenManager() 
sm.add_widget(StartScreen(name = "startscreen")) 
sm.add_widget(SettingScreen(name = "settingscreen")) 
sm.add_widget(LevelScreen(name = "levelscreen"))  



class CubesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample_app = CubesApp() 
    sample_app.run()
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
 ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading root widget. See https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/wiki/Modules-Material-App#exceptions
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему. Гугл конечно же сказал что нужно иницилизировать до запуска, но как?

Comment: Попробуйте добавление виджетов делать после создания `sample_app = CubesApp()`, но перед `sample_app.run()`

Comment: Незнаю прошел я на шаг вперед или назад, но теперь вылетает другая ошибка   ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be inherited from `kivymd.app.MDApp`

Comment: Все, нашел в общем я сделал как вы порекомендовали и еще по мелочи, спасибо большое